# Use Controller Laravel 8 Variable value for Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have stored procedure query for calculate Distance..
But, i have dummy value for latitude and longitude in Controller Laravel 8..

Here's my Contoller:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
{
    $latitude = "-6.190054983260954";
    $longitude = "106.79885292237778";

    $cities = City::all();
    $city = $request->get('city_name');
    $search = $request->get('keyword');

    $getDistance = DB::select('CALL home_search(' . $city . ', ' . $search . ')');

    return view('pages.index', [
        'getDistance' => $getDistance,
    ]);
}
```

Here's mysql Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `home_search` ()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM pharmacies, cities , SQRT(POW(($latitude - pharmacy_lat ), 2) +
        POW(($longitude - pharmacy_long), 2)) * 111.319 AS distance
        WHERE city = $city AND city_address LIKE '%VALUE_FROM_SEARCH_IN_LARAVEL%'
        ORDER BY distance, asc 
        LIMIT 3
END
```

Do you know how to add laravel controller variable's value for be used to my stored procedure query?

Comment: Same way you did here: `CALL home_search(' . $city . ', ' . $search . ')`

Comment: Is my mysql stored procedure query right?

Answer (score 0):

so, i only to set paramaters on my Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `home_search`(
 latitude decimal(11, 7),
 longitude decimal(11, 7),
 city varchar(255),
 search varchar(255)
)
```